# Adding numeric column to pyspark DataFrame based on string value of column

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I've got a DataFrame built from a JSON file:

```
{ "1": "a b c d e f", "2": 1, "type": "type1"}
{ "1": "a b c b c", "2": 2, "type": "type1"}
{"1": "d d a b c", "2": 3, "type": "type2"}
...
```

I'm designing a Naive Bayes classifier and such DataFrame is my training set: the classifier will use features extracted from field *1* and the class (label) is given by field *type*.

My problem is I get this error when fitting the model:

> pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Column type must be of type DoubleType but was actually StringType.'

which is indicating the label field must be numeric. To solve the issue, I'm trying to map the string values to numeric values through a dict as

```
grouped = df.groupBy(df.type).agg({'*': 'count'}).persist()
types = {row.type: grouped.collect().index(row) for row in grouped.collect()}
```

and then the idea is to add a new column to the DataFrame with the numeric value corresponding to its string value:

```
df = df.withColumn('type_numeric', types[df.type])
```

This of course fails, so I was wondering whether anyone has better ideas or suggestions on how to achieve this.

Comment: Hi,please rend your question and first write cod then result you expect and finally the error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved by using the StringIndexer to the DataFrame.

```
string_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='type', outputCol='type_numeric')
rescaled_data_numeric = string_indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
```